# android opengl texImage2D: internalformat and type parameters

Tags: android, opengl-es

in android `texImage2D`  (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLUtils.html)
we have theses 2 functions :

```
void texImage2D (int target, 
                 int level, 
                 Bitmap bitmap, 
                 int border)

void texImage2D (int target, 
                int level, 
                int internalformat, 
                Bitmap bitmap, 
                int type, 
                int border)
```

one don't need the **internalformat** and **type** and the other function need it. What could be the drawback of the first variant (the one who don't need the internalformat and type) ? If their is no drawback why the other variant even exist? Note that I don't know what the purpose of internalformat and type is, normally in my OpenGL program I always use rgba as internalformat and type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `internal_format` in OpenGL is used to specify the exact format each pixel should have in memory. `type'  specifies which format the incoming data (in android the bitmap) has.

The first version (the one not having an internal format parameter) determines the internal format and the type from the `bitmap.colorType()`.

There is no real problem with the first version of `texImage2D`, but it limits the possible internal format. It will, for example, not be possible to create floating point textures, 16bit or 32bit textures or integer textures. You can have a look at the [`getInternalFormat` method](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/jni/android/opengl/util.cpp#L651) which determines the internal format to see which formats are supported. If you want any internal format that is not returned there, one has to call `texImage2D` with the exact internal format needed.

Comment: thanks BDL! by the way what the advantage to have 16 or 32 bit textures ?

Comment: If you want to do HDR rendering or a lot of other effects, you will need that. For "normal" color textures, 8 bits are usually sufficient.